# Customise title in the WK Status Bar

Tags: watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

I'm trying to customise title in the WK Status Bar of my first Controller.

[image]

The correct way should be this:

```
public func setTitle(title: String?) // title of controller. displayed when controller active
```

so

```
WKInterfaceController.setTitle("my Title")
```

but using this code, xCode says `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'WKInterfaceController'`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTitle` is an instance method, not a class method.

You need to refer to a specific instance controller to change that controller's title.  Since you would generally be setting your first controller's title within its own code, you can omit self, and simply call

```
setTitle("my Title")
```